# Create a custom user email

Tags: php, email, woocommerce

I actually wish to have a custom email when a user signs up on the website.

Here is the existing code:

```
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Thanks for creating an account on %1$s. Your username is %2$s. You can access your account area to view orders, change your password, and more at: %3$s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $blogname ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_login ) . '</strong>', make_clickable( esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></p>
```

current result:

> Thanks for creating an account on (website name). Your username is (user name). You can access your account area to view orders, change your password, and more at: https://www.(website name).com/beta/my-account/

I wish to have this message:

> Thank you for signing up. Message us 1000 on WhatsApp to select your free gift with your first purchase. Click Here (click here has a link to WhatsApp).

I am done with the text part but stuck with Click here. Please let me know the code and its placement. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Do you mean you want the system to "create" an email address (create a new email account, able to send / receive emails) for those who signs up ?

Comment: Are you sending your email in HTML or Plain Text? Please show more code on how you're actually sending the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want to change the default email template when a user creates a new account.

This email template can be found at : `woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-new-account.php` and the line you wish to change is [L25 here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/templates/emails/customer-new-account.php#L25).

If you go through the documentation [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) you will see.

> Edit files in an upgrade-safe way using overrides. Copy the template into a directory within your theme named /woocommerce keeping the same file structure but removing the /templates/ subdirectory.

> Example: To override the admin order notification, copy: wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php to wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php

What you have to do is to copy the contents of `customer-new-account.php` and inside your theme ( [preferably child theme because of this](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/set-up-and-use-a-child-theme/) ) create a file here  wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-new-account.php
and update the line 25 as such.

```
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Thank you for signing up. Message us 1000 on WhatsApp to select your free gift with your first purchase. %1$s).', 'woocommerce' ), make_clickable( esc_url( 'Add URL HERE' ) ) ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></p>
```

You can also go to this page `wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=email&section=wc_email_customer_new_account` and hit this button to automatically copy template to your theme.

[image: Copy template]

> Click on `Copy file to theme`